# MySQL - Group by similar rows (not the same exactly)

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following

[image]

Is there any way I can group rows that have a similar content_type, for example, sort all the rows that start with 'application' or 'image'. Maybe with a regex, I haven't been able to figure it out

The query is the following:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(timings_wait), 2) AS total
    , res_h_value AS content_type
    , DAYOFWEEK(startedDateTime) AS d
    , HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(startedDateTime
    ,'%Y-%c-%d %T')) AS h     
FROM req_res_head    
INNER JOIN entries ON req_res_head.entry_id = entries.id    
WHERE res_h_name = 'content-type'    
GROUP BY content_type

ORDER BY d;
```

EDIT: Sorry for the image, it's just to show a sample of the table. Also I am using SQL version 5.7.26

Thanks in advance

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question to have a [mre] also add your mysql version, the new versioncan much mre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the version of the database we could be more accurate for the moment i can answer with this:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(timings_wait), 2) AS total, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(res_h_value, '/', 1) AS content_type,
    DAYOFWEEK(startedDateTime) AS d,
    HOUR(DATE_FORMAT(startedDateTime,'%Y-%c-%d %T')) AS h     
FROM req_res_head    
INNER JOIN entries ON req_res_head.entry_id = entries.id    
WHERE res_h_name = 'content-type'    
GROUP BY content_type
ORDER BY d;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Marco's answer, you can create a completely arbitrary grouping using [the `CASE` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case):

```
SELECT
  (
    CASE
      WHEN LOCATE('/', content_type, LOCATE('/', content_type) + 1) <> 0 THEN 'invalid' -- more than 1 slash in content_type
      WHEN SUBSTRING(content_type FROM 1 FOR 9) = 'image/png' THEN 'PNG image'
      WHEN SUBSTRING(content_type FROM 1 FOR 6) = 'image/' THEN 'other image'
      WHEN SUBSTRING(content_type FROM 1 FOR 12) = 'application/' THEN 'application'
      ELSE 'unknown'
    END
  ) AS classifier,
  COUNT(0)
FROM
  partresult
GROUP BY
  classifier
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e2f0/4/0) for an example.